# ISAPI Extension on IIS using Basing authentication returns wrong user in GetUserName

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi

I have a SOAP Server running as ISAPI Extension under IIS. For authentification I decided to use IIS's built-in basic authentification. In the SOAP Server I just need to know username of the user connecting to the ISAPI. As to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525338%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Before IIS processes a request, authentication of the client is performed in order to set the security context (or identity) of the process that executes the request.

I hoped to get the username of the caller with the function `GetUserName`.

This is the implementation code of the SOAP Server:

```
TTestSOAP = class(TSOAPDataModule, ITestSOAP)
public
  function WhoAmI: String; stdcall;
end;

function TTestSOAP.WhoAmI: String;
var
  WinName: String;
  BufSize: DWord;
  Buffer: PWideChar;
begin
 BufSize:= 1024;
 Buffer:= AllocMem(BufSize);
 try
    if GetUserName(Buffer, BufSize) then
      SetString(WinName, Buffer, BufSize)
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    FreeMem(Buffer);
  end;
  Result:= Format('You are: %s', [WinName]);
end;
```

The ISAPI dll is build with Delphi 2009 and uses ISAPIThreadPool unit.

Normally everything works fine and I am getting correct username. But under heavy load I get missmatched results. ie: on the client side I create testing threads that Connect to the SOAP Server, call the WhoAmI function 5 times in a loop and disconnect. Running three or more of those thread each with different user the Usernames returned by WhoAmI function become randomly exchanged.
For example: Thread connecting as 'user1' gets 'You are: user2' on some (not all) of the 5 calls.

Does anybody have a clue on whats going on in here?
Do you know of a secure and correct way of getting username in SOAPDataModule that the client have been authenticated to the IIS with?

**Edit:**
Did some more testing and debugging:
In the WhoAmI function implementation I added this code `LogonName:= GetSOAPWebModule.Request.GetFieldByName('AUTH_USER');`. It reports the same username as GetUserName.
It seems that the problem happens on the client side. So a few details about the client:
Mentioned threads create HTTPRio component (each thread its own HTTPRio). For authorization I set Rio.HTTPWebNode.UserName and Rio.HTTPWebNode.Password. After HTTPRio.HTTPWebNode.Connect(True) I do call ITestSOAP(HTTPRio).WhoAmI in a loop.

Is it possible that Winet that's behind HTTPRio does mismatch the usernames for multiple HTTPRio components each running in different thread but is the same process (application)?

Comment: Sounds like a race condition of some sort.

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: I thought the same. But then it'd have to be in IIS "extension launcher". Which would be a majore fault that I do not believe wouldn't be reported somewhere already.I did some more testing and found the problem might be on the client side. See Edited question.

Comment: or it might be in the Delphi abstraction layer that sits on top of ISAPI, or your layer that sits on top of that. Do you have a simple reproducible case?